# What plugins are in use on wordpress.com

Tags: plugins, wordpress.com-hosting

is there a list of plugins that are in use on WordPress.com somewhere?

It would be very interesting to see how they have implemented specific widgets and functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an easy question to answer. That stuff is mostly private and they seem to use greatly modified versions of some public plugins.

[wordpresscom](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/wordpresscom) tag in repository has several.

Also see this topic for more ideas and places to check [List of plugins used on WordPress.com](http://www.wptavern.com/forum/plugins-hacks/1777-list-plugins-used-wordpress-com.html)

Comment: Thanks, but your answer was a bit disappointing since I thought they might publish their code according to the GPL?

Comment: As long as they don't redistribute code and purely use it for wordpress.com there is no obligation under GPL to share it. Some stuff gets released, some doesn't.